# Trouble with shutting down screen in Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 server on old laptop with damaged lid - it can't be closed. This fact doesn't bother me, but I do want to shutdown the screen without closing the lid, and only by using commands.

I found such solution: `sudo vbetool dpms off`, but it returned an error:

```
mmap /dev/zero: Operation not permitted
Failed to initialise LRMI (Linux Real-Mode Interface)
```

After some digging i found such solution:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev
```

And now I can use commands `sudo vbetool dpms off` and `sudo vbetool dpms on` without any error, but also without any visible effect.

I tried also use `xset` but as far as I know on server version with command line only I do not have X available, and `vbetool` is the way to do this.

Right now I have no idea what to do, how to shut down the screen, or what additional information could I provide. Please note, that my first contact with linux systems was yesterday, so I'm not really aware what `sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev` really does and why it does not work after removing any errors.

Comment: `mount -o remount,exec /dev` removes `noexec` which prevents files in `/dev` from ever being executed. I think there is no reason to allow execution other than [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581984/108618): "there are still programs that memory-map `/dev/zero` with `PROT_EXEC` for no good reason". It seems `vbetool` is one of these.

Comment: Thanks for this information - I'll do `mount -o remount,noexec /dev` to redo the change. Yet my original problem remains unsolved - could You help me with it? Perhaps `vbetool` is not the right way to turn off screen, but I'm unable to find any other solution, and this one does not work.

Comment: If I could have helped you with the original problem, I would have already written an answer. For now I cannot.

Comment: on Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS, ```sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev``` followed by ```sleep 1; vbetool dpms off``` works for me. Thanks @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: @PravyNandas I'm still getting the same error quoted in the post `Operation not permitted`...

Comment: @Zorann before performing this change, I followed other post to set the DISPLAY environment variable to zero (0) or collan-zero (:0) . Please review the comment here https://askubuntu.com/a/516151/732216

Comment: @PravyNanda The commend `export DISPLAY=:0` does not work for me. Can this be done in the command line only enviroment? AFAIK in my case I can not use xset - or am I wrong?

Comment: Mine is command line only environment (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) and if `export DISPLAY=:0` not works, you can try `export DISPLAY=0` (removing the collon). Give a try.

Comment: Both commands does not do anything (no effect or error at all), and if I'm trying `sudo export DISPLAY=:0` with or without colon, it returns `sudo: export: command not found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I actually got an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277533/ubuntu-20-04-on-a-laptop-is-there-any-way-toturn-off-the-screen/1350374#1350374

To turn off the screen:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev
sudo vbetool dpms off
sudo mount -o remount,noexec /dev
```

In order to turn it on again:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev
sudo vbetool dpms on
sudo mount -o remount,noexec /dev
```

It works! For me at least... Hope it will work as well for any google user that ends up in this place.